# How to find PDF from CDF?

Tags: statistics

My textbook defines the PDF of a continous RV as any function $f_X:R\rightarrow R$ satisfying:

$$F_X(x) = \int^x_{-\infty}f_X(t)dt$$

From the fundamental theorem, we have that if $f_X$ is continous at some $c\in R$, then $F_X$ is differentiable at $c$ with $F'_X(c)=f_X(c)$.

Suppose I am given a CDF of some continous random variable and wish to find its associated PDF. How would I find the PDF without knowing beforehand if its associated PDF is continuous?

If I knew that $f_X$ is continous, then I could use the relation $F'_X(c)=f_X(c)$ at those $c$ at which $f_X$ is continous and $F_X$ is differentiable to find the PDF from the CDF.

But what if the PDF were discontinous? Then the FTC need not apply and the relation $F'_X(c)=f_X(c)$ may not necessarily hold?

Comment: A continuous random variable need not even have a pdf. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution#:~:text=The%20Cantor%20distribution%20is%20the%20unique%20probability%20distribution%20for%20which,of%20the%202t%20intervals) is an example of such an annomaly. In general you cannot recover a pdf from a cdf. You need something called absolute continuity to apply an important theorem called Radon-Nikodym theorem that would guarantee the existence of a pdf.

Comment: However, I think you are not in a Probability Theory(measure theoratic) course since your book has defined a random variable $X$ as one having a pdf . But the standard definition of a continuous rv is that a rv is continuous if it has a continuous cdf. However, if you can do a bit of digging into what "measure zero" sets are, then you can directly say that the pdf is $f_{X}$ from your definition upto a set of measure zero. It would not affect the value of the cdf . It is a result from Lebesgue-Vitali and it can be proven without going into too much depth of measure theory.

Comment: Take a simple discontinuous density, such as $f(x)=1$ when $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x <0$ or $x>1$, which is discontinuous at $x=0$ and $x=1$.  Then $F(x)=0$ when $x \le 0$, $F(x)=x$ when $0 \le x \le 1$, and $F(x)=1$ when $x \ge 1$.  You can see $F(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ and $x=1$ but this does not matter very much as the probability of one of those happening is $0$.